# Gedit select text and just highlight it plugin

Tags: gedit

Does anyone know how to highlight some text or change its color in Gedit 3.4.1?

I have a list of features or modules to include in my project and I just want to mark each as solved when am done with it. Just a simple highlight or color change will do.

Thanxs.

Comment: You might want to use Libre Office Writer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Gedit is just an editor and not intended for publishing/presentation this feature is unlikely to be found. Have yourself a look at the [list of available plugins](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins) though.

As a workaround I suggest you go to *View/Highlight Mode* and select some script (I used `sh`). Now every line that has a `#` at the beginning is displayed differently.

[image]

Comment: Its not exactly what I was looking for but its a nice workaround. Thanxs.

Answer (score 1):

In **Gedit** go to **View** → **Highlight Mode** and select what kind of highlight mode do you wish:

[image: gedit - Highlight Mode]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gedit-plugins` to enable a lot of features in `Gedit`. Install it and just enable it to access the features you want.

Follow these simple steps:

- Install `gedit-plugins`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
  ```
- Once installed open `Gedit` and enable plugins:

  - Click Edit -> Preferences
  - Go to `Plugins`.
  - Mark the checkboxes for the plugins you want to enable.
  - Thats it.
- For more plugins and help you can go for following sites:

  - [Configure and use gedit Plugins](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugin-guide.html.en)
  - [13 Gedit Plugins to Make It a More Useful Text Editor](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-plugins-to-extend-and-make-gedit-a-more-useful-text-editor-linux/)

Hope this short description somewhat helps you..